# Java - checksum for reliable data transfer protocol over UDP

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, checksum

I am implementing a reliable data transfer protocol over UDP. The packets may get corrupted, hence I have to use checksum to to determine which packet is corrupted or not. As my RDT protocol is a stop-and-wait protocol, I send one packet and wait for an response.

I am using CRC32 to calculate the checksum.

```
Checksum checksum = new CRC32();  

checksum.update(packet.getData(),0,packet.getLength());  

long value = checksum.getValue();
```

The question is, how do I use the checksum value at the sender's end to compare with the packet's checksum value at the receiver's end? Do I append the sender's checksum to the packet and let the receiver update its own checksum by reading the received packet before the beginning of the checksum value?

For example, at the receiver's side:

```
receiverChecksum.update(packet.getData(),0,packet.getLength - checksumLength());
```

Is my approach correct? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, with UDP the risk is that the packet will not arrive at all.  Data corruption is relatively rare nowadays as UDP itself already contains a checksum. You shouldn't need to worry about data corruption. Focus on packet loss instead.

Comment: I see, I will definitely work on the packet loss issue. As right now, my concern is to manage corrupted packet. How do I use the checksum that's already contained in UDP packet to compare?

Comment: You don't have to. If it's corrupt it won't arrive.

Comment: Actually I'm using a simulated UDP protocol provided by the professor, not the actual UDP we are using on the Internet. So the corrupted packet will arrive at the receiver.